# Cython/C++ - header file paths in shared PXD file

Tags: c++, python, cython

I have a project consisting of several Cython modules in different folders:

```
clibs
  File.cpp
  File.hpp
module
  module/folder
    __init__.py
    file1.pyx
    file1.pxd
  __init__.py
  file2.pyx
```

In `module/folder/file1.pxd` I have something like this:

```
cdef extern from "../../clibs/File.hpp":
    cdef cppclass MyCppClass:
        int _data
        MyCppClass(int arg)

cdef class MyPyClass:
    cdef MyCppClass* cpp_obj
```

and then in `module/file2.pyx` I `cimport` the declarations from `module/folder/file1.pxd`:

```
from module.folder.file1 cimport MyCppClass, MyPyClass
```

Now, when I try to build this, cython generates the line

```
#include "../../clibs/File.hpp"
```

when reading `module/folder/file1.pxd`, and drops it into the newly generated `module/file2.cpp`, which is obviously an invalid path!

How do I resolve this? Can I specify a path relative to the project root in my `extern` clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My (temporary) solution to this is to create a symbolic link to the `clibs` directory in every python folder.

To stop this being a problem with version control, I've added the following to the top and the bottom of my `setup.py`:

```python
# at the top:
import os
pwd = os.getcwd()

folders = [
    "module",
    "module/folder"
]

for f in folders:
    os.system("ln -s " + pwd + "/clibs " + f + "/clibs")

try:
    # setup commands...
finally:
    # used here so that if setup raises a compilation exception, we 
    # still tidy up:

    for f in folders:
        os.system("rm " + f + "/clibs")
```

*notes:* you need the full `pwd` - if you just specify the local folder name that's all that gets stored in the symlink, and you get an ELOOP too many symlinks error.

I still want a better solution to this, this is just a dirty hack, and only valid when `ln -s` and `rm` are there! If nothing else is posted, I'll eventually mark this as "accepted", but this shouldn't be necessary at all.

Update: Another bug is that when the code is on a networked filesystem (e.g. in a shared folder in VirtualBox) you are not allowed to create symlinks on the guest - very frustrating!